# Tree to generate for jsTree

Tags: php, jstree

```
function createJsonTree($array, $currentParent, $currLevel = 0, $prevLevel = -1) {

 foreach ($array as $categoryId => $category) {

  if ($currentParent == $category['parent']) {      

   if ($currLevel > $prevLevel) $output .= ' , "children":[ '; 

   if ($currLevel == $prevLevel) $output .= " }, ";

    $output .= '{ "data" :'.'"'.$category['menu_title'].'"';

   if ($currLevel > $prevLevel) { $prevLevel = $currLevel; }

   $currLevel++; 

    $output .= self::createJsonTree($array, $category['id'], $currLevel, $prevLevel);

    $currLevel--;      
  } 

 }

 if ($currLevel == $prevLevel) $output .= " }] ";
 return $output;
}
```

Comment: You need to explain your question in more detail. Posting a title and a wall of code doesn't make it easy for us to help you. What do you want to do, what have you managed to do, what is it you do now that is different from what you would like to do?

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason that json_encode won't work for this?

https://www.php.net/json_encode

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a tree like this:

```
function createTree()
{
    $sql = "SELECT id, parent_id, title FROM category order by id ";
    $filas = UtilConexion::$pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $arbol = '{"data":[{"attr":{"id":"000"},"data":"Nodo raíz","state":"open"' .
    $this->createJsonTree($filas, null) . '}]}';
    return $arbol;
}
```